# I want to perform in place modification to a std::map while iterating over it

Tags: c++

I need to know the best way to do the in place modification to the map without taking a local copy of the values modified and then pushing it again into the original map.

I have detailed the snippet below that explains the problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
struct EmployeeKey
{
    std::string name;
    int amount;
    int age;
};

struct EmployeeDetail
{
    std::string dept;
    int section;
    int salary;
};

bool compareByNameAge(const std::string& name,
                      const int& age,
                      const EmployeeKey& key )
{
    return name > key.name && age > key.age;
}

typedef std::map<EmployeeKey, EmployeeDetail> EmployeeMap;

int main()
{
    EmployeeMap eMap;
    // insert entries to the map
    int age = 10;
    std::string name = "John";

    EmployeeMap transformMap;
    foreach( iter, eMap )
    {
        if ( compareByNameAge(name, age, iter->first) )
        {
            //**This is what i want to avoid.......
            // take a copy of the data modified
            // push it in a new map.
            EmployeeDetail det = iter->second;
            det.salary = 1000;
            transformMap[iter->first] = det;
        }
    }

    //** Also, i need to avoid too...  
    // do the cpy of the modified values   
    // from the transform map to the   
    // original map  
    foreach( iter1, transformMap )  
        eMap[iter1->first] = iter1->second;
}
```

Comment: Add the reference.  EmployeeDetail &det = iter->secondl; will change the copy in the map.

Comment: For a simple modification like you do, it should work to do it in place: `iter->second.salary = 1000;`. It's when changing the key, or inserting/removing items from the collection you can't do it.

Comment: This doesn't work. as the for_each version supports only const_iterators.

Comment: @SidharthShekahr: So use a normal `for` loop (range-based, if your compiler supports it), or `std::for_each`, or `BOOST_FOREACH`; or fix your custom `foreach` to give non-const iterators.

Comment: What's `foreach`? I'm pretty sure that's not a C++ keyword.

Comment: @mike: 
can you suggest a way to do boost::bind with std::transform on the map so that the comparator is invoked from the std::transform for every key and i avoid this iteration and let transform do the stuff.

Comment: @Rob: this is the foreach macro:  #ifdef __GNUC__
 #define foreach(it, cont) \
  for( const typeof(cont) &UNIQUE_NAME(_c) = cont, *pt = &UNIQUE_NAME(_c); pt != NULL; pt = NULL ) \
   for ( typeof(UNIQUE_NAME(_c).begin()) it=UNIQUE_NAME(_c).begin(); it!=UNIQUE_NAME(_c).end(); ++it )
#else
 #error "TODO: Implement foreach() for this compiler"
#endif // __GNUC__

Comment: can someone suggest a way to do boost::bind with std::transform on the map so that the comparator is invoked from the std::transform for every key and i avoid this iteration and let transform do the stuff.

Comment: @Sid: note that transform iterates too, so the iteration is not avoided, but move at some other place.

Comment: `const typeof(cont) &UNIQUE_NAME(_c) = cont`. There's your problem. You are iterating through a const reference to your container. If you own the `foreach` macro, just fix it. Otherwise, ... do something else. Do you have C++11?

Answer (score 9):

You can simply modifiy the element directly through the iterator (which points directly to the corresponding item):

```
foreach(iter, eMap)  
{  
   if (compareByNameAge(name, age, iter->first))  
     iter->second.salary = 1000;   
}
```

for more complex modifications you could take the value by reference:

```
EmployeeDetail& det = iter->second;  
det.salary = 1000;
```

In c++ you can typically not modify a collection while iterating, but that only means that you can't remove/add items. Modifying existing items is typically fine in C++11. What you can't modify is the key in a `map` and any part of the element in `set`, but those are `const` in c++11 anyways, so you can't modify those. In C++03 you need to remember not to change the keypart of an element in a `set`.

Answer (score 6):

`iter->second` is a reference to the `EmployeeDetail` object, which you can modify directly - e.g.

```
   foreach( iter, eMap )  
   {  
       if ( compareByNameAge(name, age, iter->first) )  
       {
           iter->second.salary = 1000;
       }  
   }
```

No need for the `transformMap`

Comment: can you suggest a way to do boost::bind with std::transform so that i avoid this iteration and let transform do the stuff ..

Comment: @Sid, you're not really avoiding the iteration, it's just hidden by some fancy syntax, why not leave it as is? It's very readable what is happening (aside from your custom `foreach`), in c++11, this becomes even simpler `for(auto it : eMap) { ... }`

Comment: @Sid: You cannot use `transform` with `bind` directly for this, as you are not *transforming* the container, but rather modifying *only some* of the values, which means that you will still need the `if` or a functor, and at the end the complexity of the code will be greater than the plain iteration, making the code less maintainable, unless of course you write a small lambda, in which case it will be just as maintainable, but the `transform` approach will be slightly more inefficient as it will rewrite all elements, even those not modified.

Answer (score 4):

Just take a reference to the value.

```
EmployeeDetail& det = iter->second;   // notice new '&' character.
det.salary = 1000;   // modifies the 'EmployeeDetail' object in-place.
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do the following?

```
it->second.salary = 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't just iterating over the map and doing

iter->second.salary = 1000;

solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to alter the values of the `map` objects (the `second` part of the `value_type`) during `foreach` iteration. You just can't add or remove any keys--no `insert` or `erase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `std::transform` because it assigns iterators, and the `first` element of a map iterator is always const.

Additionally your code doesn't show us the comparison for your employee key, so I'll assume you have one that implements strict weak ordering. A basic outline:

You can use `for_each` though, since the predicate can be stateless:

```
class SalaryUpdater
{
public:
    SalaryUpdater(const std::string& name, int age) : name_(name), age_(age) { }

    void operator()(EmployeeMap::value_type& item)
    {
        if(compareByNameAge(name_, age_, item.first))
        {
            item.second.salary = 1000;
        }
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
    int age_;
};

int main()
{
    EmployeeMap eMap;
    // insert entries to the map

    std::for_each(eMap.begin(), eMap.end(), SalaryUpdater("John", 10));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the EmployeeDetail.

Comment: I cannot get the reference of the EmployeeDetail as the for_each version we have supports const_iterators.

Comment: @Sid: Just write the loop yourself, that is much less code, much easier to read and maintain, and much more runtime and memory efficient than your idea of copying stuff multiple times around.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11, try this:

```
for (auto& pair : eMap )
  if (pair.first.name == "Rob")
    pair.second.salary *= 1000;
```

Note: you can only change `pair.second`. `pair.first` is const, and must not be changed (it is, after all, the key to the map.)

If you don't have C++11, try this:

```
for(EmployeeMap::iterator it = eMap.begin(); it != eMap.end(); ++it)
  if(pair.first.name == "Rob")
    pair.second.hours /= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

C++17 update with structured bindings:

```
for (auto &[key, detail] : employeeMap)
    if (compareByNameAge(name, age, key))  
        detail.salary = 1000;
```